# generator-fountain-webapp installation error

Tags: yeoman-generator-angular

I am trying to install generator-fountain-webapp. 
When I do "yo fountain-webapp", I am getting the below error. Any suggestions?

```
yo fountain-webapp
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-fountain-webapp/generators/app/index.js:6
 initializing() {
             ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
   at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
   at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
   at require (module.js:384:17)
   at Object.defineProperty.get [as fountain-webapp:app] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/store.js:40:23)
   at Store.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/store.js:64:35)
   at Environment.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:260:16)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just encountered the same problem. I managed to fixed it by updating node and npm.

You can download the latest version from the [node site](https://nodejs.org/en/). Or if you installed node with homebrew you can use `brew upgrade node`

Comment: Why can't these things check what version is installed and announce what is needed rather than just crashing out?